# AngularJS - understanding scopes

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, scope, angularjs

I'm confused, I have this module which routes to different controllers:

```
var mainModule = angular.module('lpConnect', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {template:'views/home.html', controller:HomeCtrl}).
        when('/admin', {template:'views/admin.html', controller:AdminCtrl}).
        when('/connect', {template:'views/fb_connect.html', controller:MainAppCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/connect'});
}]);
```

and a Common service like so:

```
mainModule.factory('Common', ['$rootScope', '$http', function (scope, http) {
        var methods = {
            changeLanguage:function (langID) {
                http.get('JSON/langs/' + langID + '/captions.json').success(function (data) {
                    scope.lang = data;
                });
            },
            initChat:function () {
                console.log(scope); // full object
                console.log(scope.settings); // undefined
            }
        };

        //initiate
        http.get('JSON/settings/settings.json').success(function (data) {
            scope.settings = data;
            methods.changeLanguage(scope.settings.lang);
        });


        return methods;
    }]);
```

the app loads and gets (through XHR) the settings object, and I can see the settings reflects in my DOM. (captions for example)

Now when I call the initChat method from my HomeCtrl I get an undefined value when trying to access the scope.settings property ... what's strange is that when I log the scope I can see the settings object ... What am I missing?

[image]

**Update:** I found out that what I'm doing wrong is calling my method directly from the controller body:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $location, Common) {
...
Common.initChat()
...
}
```

if I change the call to be triggered by a click all works fine, but I do need this code to run when the page loads, What is the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. http is async and that is your main problem (as Andy astutely pointed out)
2. ng-init is not recommended for production code, initializing in controllers is better
3. initializing your scope.settings = {} or a decent default may help you, once xhr is done then your settings will be available.

hope this helps

--dan

Comment: Could you elaborate more on 2nd statement?

Comment: If you think about it, using ng-init pollutes your web page with static content. If you use a scope variable in a controller then you are better separating concerns. Note, if you have javascript function that expects values to be defined, then you should assign default values in your controller. I typically create a controller init method that I call towards the end of a controller.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple problem, I think: You're calling initChat in your scope before the $http call retrieves scope.settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, That was the case ... the question is what is the best way to sync the process, for now I solved the issue with ng-init="initChat()" on my root node. Not sure it is the best way